# Can't get data using Magic Eden API

Tags: nft, python, nfts, magiceden

I checked [Magic Eden API documentation](https://api.magiceden.dev/#11c4283e-7940-4592-b445-f9b512ccf21c) and wanted to see all the tokens from my wallet.
Example from the documentation:

```
import requests

url = "api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/wallets/EWmtsfBA8EikR3vvhsXgxn7cBQCUZfXJ7jMwXUpYRzXY/tokens?offset=0&limit=100&listStatus=listed"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

The code above is pretty simple, and I decided to copy-paste the link to my browser, change the wallet address to my own and change "listStatus" parameter to "both".

So my link was *https://api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/wallets/6xX3z7uxTNB68izZW2GHKnzno49dizqeVVc5ncVzdjFM/tokens?offset=0&limit=100&listStatus=both
*

Result: []

Why do I get this result? Am I doing something wrong or is there something wrong with Magic Eden's API?

I tried pasting other wallets, some random ones from Magic Eden and I'm CERTAIN there were tokens in those wallets, but the result was the same with every new wallet.

Note: Right now I have 12 unlisted items on my account, so I don't know why the link returns an empty list.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as you....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3205)